# Integrate AEM Adobe Adaptive forms into angular app

Tags: angular, aem

I would like to know how do I integrate some AEM Adaptive Froms into my frontend which is in Angular.

Does anyone know how ?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Didn’t use it yet but came across this GitHub repository for running AEM Forms Headless a while back. https://github.com/adobe/aem-forms-af-runtime

Alternatively you can load your forms in an iframe..

Comment: Thanks for your answer but is there an equivalent method in angular instead of react.js ?

Comment: Also, my adaptive forms are based on XML not Json.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).